# Netty gRPC Connection Refused in Docker

Tags: java, docker, grpc

I'm running a Docker container (GPC Spanner) and attempting to create an instance using org.testcontainers.containers (from a Junit BeforeClass).  The connection is refused.

```
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9010

Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Code:

```
  private static final Integer[] SPANNER_EMULATOR_PORTS = {9010, 9020};

  private static final WaitStrategy WAIT_FOR_START_LOG_MESSAGE =
      Wait.forLogMessage(".*gRPC server listening.*", 1).withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
...

   final GenericContainer<?> container =
        new GenericContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse(emulatorDockerImage))
            .withExposedPorts(SPANNER_EMULATOR_PORTS)
            .waitingFor(
                new WaitStrategy() {
                  @Override
                  public void waitUntilReady(WaitStrategyTarget waitStrategyTarget) {
                    // do not wait on #start call, so that we can hook up logger and print output
                    // for errors which we can do only after #start is invoked
                  }
              @Override
              public WaitStrategy withStartupTimeout(Duration startupTimeout) {
                return this;
              }
            });

final StringBuilder containerOutput = new StringBuilder();
final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
try {
  System.out.println("Running Spanner Emulator Container");
  container.start();
  // TODO: See if there's a way to print the output as it's happening and not on timeout
  recordOutput(containerOutput, startTime, "Container initialized\n");
} catch (Throwable ex) {
  throw new RuntimeException(
      "Failed to start up Spanner Emulator",
      ex);
}

container.followOutput(
    outputFrame -> recordOutput(containerOutput, startTime, outputFrame.getUtf8String()));
try {
  WAIT_FOR_START_LOG_MESSAGE.waitUntilReady(container);
  // we print only errors in the tests
  System.err.println(
      "It took "
          + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000
          + " seconds to init Spanner");
} catch (Exception e) {
  recordOutput(containerOutput, startTime, "Explicit timeout");
  throw new RuntimeException("Spanner initialization timeout\n" + containerOutput, e);
}

SpannerEmulatorContainer spannerEmulatorContainer = new SpannerEmulatorContainer(container);
spannerEmulatorContainer.createSpannerClient(projectId);
return spannerEmulatorContainer;
...
InstanceAdminClient instanceAdminClient = spanner.getInstanceAdminClient();

// Create a instance
InstanceInfo instanceInfo =
    InstanceInfo.newBuilder(
            InstanceId.of(TestConstants.testProjectId, TestConstants.testInstanceId))
        .setInstanceConfigId(
            InstanceConfigId.of(TestConstants.testProjectId, TestConstants.testRegion))
        .setNodeCount(1)
        .setDisplayName(TestConstants.testInstanceId)
        .build();
// ***** Errors out here ******
OperationFuture<Instance, CreateInstanceMetadata> instanceOperation =
    instanceAdminClient.createInstance(instanceInfo);
```

Std Out:

```
2022-10-09T01:35:40.244-0700 [DEBUG] [TestEventLogger]     It took 3 seconds to init ...
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                              NAMES
a0d09b8a15f4   gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator:1.4.6   "./gateway_main --ho…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:55082->9010/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55081->9020/tcp   sleepy_poitras
b1315b3c091e   testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.0                      "/app"                   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   0.0.0.0:55080->8080/tcp                            testcontainers-ryuk-c0389f48-9da7-4731-9dc9-f5f03fc050e0
```

docker logs a0d09b8a15f4

```
WARNING: proto: file "google/rpc/status.proto" is already registered
    previously from: "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status"
    currently from:  "unknown"
See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go/faq#namespace-conflict

WARNING: proto: file "google/rpc/status.proto" has a name conflict over google.rpc.Status
    previously from: "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status"
    currently from:  "unknown"
See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go/faq#namespace-conflict

WARNING: proto: message google.rpc.Status is already registered
    previously from: "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status"
    currently from:  "unknown"
See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go/faq#namespace-conflict

2022/10/09 08:37:50 gateway.go:140: Cloud Spanner emulator running.
2022/10/09 08:37:50 gateway.go:141: REST server listening at 0.0.0.0:9020
2022/10/09 08:37:50 gateway.go:142: gRPC server listening at 0.0.0.0:9010
```

docker logs b1315b3c091e

```
2022/10/09 08:37:49 Pinging Docker...
2022/10/09 08:37:49 Docker daemon is available!
2022/10/09 08:37:49 Starting on port 8080...
2022/10/09 08:37:49 Started!
2022/10/09 08:37:49 Connected
2022/10/09 08:37:49 Adding {"label":{"org.testcontainers.sessionId=c0389f48-9da7-4731-9dc9-f5f03fc050e0":true,"org.testcontainers=true":true}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't using the randomized port when making the connection from the test.  The actual exposed port is different from the one it's listening to in the container.

```
String address = container.getHost();
Integer port = container.getFirstMappedPort();
```